# How to bind a jQuery plugin to an element in ASP.NET code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin which works like most plugins in this format

```
$(somelement).SomePlugin(some options); one of the options is a string.
```

Now I have a situation where the string is determined during runtime in ASP.NET in code behind and it's different for each element. This could be done in OnItemDataBound of a server control. There could be tens of them in the page.

How do I bind the jQuery plugin in code behind?

**Addition:**

Each 'someelement' can have a different id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use the HTML5 `data` attribute. For example:

```
<li data-thestringoption="some String"></li>
<li data-thestringoption="some other String"></li>
```

Then, when you invoke your plugin, you can use that `data` attribute:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    $(this).SomePlugin({
        someOption: 32,
        theStringOption: $(this).data('thestringoption')
   });
});
```

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - This'll work there too. HTML5 merely standardized it.

Comment: jQuery's support for this nice.